# pycharm numpy/tensorflow error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am importing both tf and np in pycharm. tf version of 1.6.0 and numpy version of 1.14.1. I keep running into this error. Please help -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>PycharmProjects/testflow/testflow.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "<path>PycharmProjects/testflow/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 166, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "<path>/PycharmProjects/testflow/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from .mtrand import *
  File "type.pxd", line 9, in init mtrand
ValueError: builtins.type has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 840, got 864

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code is very simple -

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], name='myname')
print (a)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(a))

b = np.array([1,2,3])
print (b)
```

Comment: Did you compile python yourself? What python version is this?

Comment: I did not compile python myself. This is python version 3.5

Comment: No ideas then. Sorry

Comment: When you do `import numpy` in python console (outside of pycharm) what happens?

Comment: works absolutely fine really.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the imports are just a little messed up from that tiny snippet.  Try something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
from numpy.random import mtrand

i = random.rand()   # Can omit the np in np.random()
j = mtrand.bytes(5)     # Can omit the np.random in np.random.mtrand.bytes(5)
print(i)
print(j)
```

Comment: All I have is this test code- import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], name='myname')
print (a)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(a))


b = np.array([1,2,3])
print (b)

Comment: Could you please update your original post with more of that code/format it a little so it's more readable?

Comment: @kernalmode it seems like a virtual environment issue.  You can set the interpreter for your project to be the main python interpreter (in Pycharm) by following the instructions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/changing-name-of-a-python-interpreter-or-virtual-environment.html

Comment: There were some packages mixed up. Cleaned up the install and works now.